# Integers not writing to file in C

Tags: c, fwrite

The following code runs fine, except my output file does not contain the integer 10, but instead the characters ^@^@^@ when I open it up in VIM. If I open it in textedit (on the mac) the file appears to be empty.

Does anybody know where I am going wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 256
#define MAX_NAME 30

int main() {
   FILE *fp;
   char fname[MAX_NAME] = "test1.dat"; 
   int x =10;
   int num= 0;

   if( (fp =fopen(fname, "w")) == NULL) {
      printf("\n fopen failed - could not open file : %s\n", fname);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }

   num= fwrite(&x, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
   printf("\n Total number of bytes written to the file = %d\n", num);

   fclose(fp);

   return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're writing binary data and expecting to see ASCII.

You could write the number in ASCII using `fprintf`: `fprintf(fp, "%d", x)`

Comment: Text mode is the default and there _IS NO_ "t" flag in standard C. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @Random832: Thanks for pointing out the error (what was I thinking?) Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is writing the *binary* representation of the four bytes `0x0000000a` to the file, i.e. `^@^@^@\n`

To write in ASCII, use `fprintf` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the binary bytes of the integer to your file, so that's what you've got.

If you want to see a textual '1', use `sprintf`. Binary files often look empty or strange in text editors.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing binary data and expecting ASCII?

If you wish to write formatted data, you can use e.g. the fprintf() function instead of fwrite().

Answer (score 0):

You're opening your file in binary, so basically, you're writing the ascii character 10, not the number 10.
Depending on what you want to do, you can open in text mode, use fprintf...